# git push error Permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: github, repository, ssh-keys

after create ssh keygen using `ssh-keygen -b 4096 -t rsa` and copy my ssh key in profile setting github, i try to push. but there is display

```
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin develop-v2

To have this happen automatically for branches without a tracking
upstream, see 'push.autoSetupRemote' in 'git help config'.
```

then i try to run  `git push --set-upstream origin develop-v2` but i have to input password, i try to input and it's return error

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

i still newbie, anyone know what happen?